# Is it normal for the UI to take up this much space?

Tags: resolution

First time user here, coming from windows 8. All the UI seems to take up way too much space, like it thinks I have the wrong resolution. All webpages load and look right but the buttons and settings are way bigger than they were in windows 8. Is there anyway I can make them 'regular' size?

In windows the chrome settings would take up nearly half this space.

[image]

My resolution is 1366x768

Comment: So you're referring to chrome/chromium resolution of the app buttons, not the desktop icons , right?

Comment: "chrome" not "chromium"? "chrome" is a 3rd party application.  The side panel with settings looks normal.

Comment: @Rinzwind meh, chromium works pretty much same way. Zoom out with Ctrl + - buttons. It's not specific to chrome. -_-|| They really should have changed names or something, cuz it's all chrome on my tongue now

Answer (score 0):

The icons in the tab: `control -` is the normal key to make websites smaller.

In "Chromium" this works (33%->):

[image]